# my socket application doesnt connect when i try it on the internet

Tags: c#, sockets, server, client

im programming a socket application using  c# (.net framework) but when i try it on the local system or private network it works well but when i try it on two different system using internet (public network) it never connect 
its my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SocketPermission me = new SocketPermission(NetworkAccess.Accept, TransportType.Tcp, "", SocketPermission.AllPorts);
        Socket mes =
            new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); 
        Socket des;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                IPHostEntry iphost = Dns.GetHostEntry("");
                IPAddress ipaddr = iphost.AddressList[0];
                MessageBox.Show(ipaddr.ToString());
                IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(ipaddr, 44444);
                label1.Text = ipaddr.ToString();
                mes.Bind(iep);
                mes.Listen(4);
                des = mes.Accept();
                MessageBox.Show("connected");
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
            }

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                IPHostEntry iphost = Dns.GetHostEntry("");
                IPAddress ipaddr = iphost.AddressList[0];
                MessageBox.Show(ipaddr.ToString());
                IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBox1.Text), 44444);
                mes.Connect(iep);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

textbox1 return server ipv6.
im using **socket permission** to open all ports for tcp .
and **ipv6** because its unique .

Comment: @RamKumaran i use `        SocketPermission me = new SocketPermission(NetworkAccess.Accept, TransportType.Tcp, "", SocketPermission.AllPorts);
` for this issue

Comment: Are both computers connected to internet via same router? If yes, check if they both have different IPV6 addresses, if not, then your ISP provides just one IPV6 address in that case you might have to do a port forward.

https://www.dslreports.com/forum/r28334244-With-IPv6-there-is-no-need-to-forward-ports

Comment: no i wrote when its a private network (like same router) or local system(both client and server on a system) it works well but when we test it on different router and public network we have this issue.its ```socket permission``` we used for port forward . but our application is a peer to peer app @RamKumaran

Comment: Could you try pinging each other with IPV6 addresses of both the machines?
https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/ping-ipv6-address-windows-linux-cli/

SocketPermission is for the socket you've configured on the particular machine, my doubt is on the router.